# How can i search for multiple string patterns in text files within a directory

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, select-string

I have a textbox that takes an input and searches a drive.

Drive for example is C:/users/me

let's say I have multiple files and subdirectories in there and I would like to search if the following strings exist in the file: "ssn" and "DOB"

Once user inputs the two strings. I split the string but space, so I can loop through the array. But here is my current code, but I'm stuck on how to proceed.

```
  gci "C:\Users\me" -Recurse | where { ($_ | Select-String -pattern ('SSN') -SimpleMatch) -or ($_ | Select-String -pattern ('DOB') -SimpleMatch ) } | ft CreationTime, Name -Wrap -GroupBy Directory | Out-String
```

this above code works if i pasted it manually into powershell but I'm trying to recreate this in a script but having confusion and how to do so.

this code below is not getting all the files needed.

```
foreach ($x in $StringArrayInputs) {
           if($x -eq $lastItem){
                $whereClause = ($_  | Select-String -Pattern $x)
            }else{
                $whereClause = ($_ | Select-String -Pattern $x) + '-or'
            } 
            $files= gci $dv -Recurse | Where { $_ | Select-String -Pattern $x -SimpleMatch} | ft CreationTime, Name -Wrap -GroupBy Directory | Out-String
}
```

Comment: You're reading the file twice when there is no need for it

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon how should I address this? Not sure how to pass each $item into the gci statement if the gci statement is not inside the loop. Can you provide a snippet on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string)'s `-Pattern` parameter accepts an *array* of strings (any one of which triggers a match), so piping directly to a *single* `Select-String` call should do:

```
$files= Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse $dv | 
          Select-String -List -SimpleMatch -Pattern $StringArrayInputs } |
            Get-Item |
              Format-Table CreationTime, Name -Wrap -GroupBy Directory |               
                Out-String
```

Note:

- Using `-File` with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) makes it return only *files*, not also directories.
- Using `-List` with `Select-String` is an optimization that ensures that at most *one* match per file is looked for and reported.
- Passing `Select-String`'s output to `Get-Item` automatically binds the `.Path` property of the former's output to the `-Path` parameter of the latter.

  - Strictly speaking, binding to `-Path` subjects the argument to interpretation as a *wildcard expression*, which, however, is generally not a concern - except if the path contains `[` characters.
  - If that is a possibility, insert a pipeline segment with `Select-Object @{ Name='LiteralPath'; Expression='Path' }` before `Get-Item`, which ensures binding to `-LiteralPath` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just followed your examples and combined both with a regex. I escaped the regex to avoid accidential usage of expressions (like a dot for any char).

It is working with my testfiles but may differ with your files. You may need to add " -Encoding UTF8" with your appropriate encoding so you may get regional specific chars as well.

```
$String = Read-Host "Enter multiple strings seperated by space to search for"
$escapedRegex = ([Regex]::Escape($String)) -replace "\\ ","|"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Attributes !Directory | Where-Object {
    $_ | Get-Content | Select-String -Pattern $escapedRegex
} | Format-Table CreationTime, Name -Wrap -GroupBy Directory | Out-String
```